# HTML not displaying correctly in outlook 2007 emails?

Tags: c#, html, outlook

EDITED:

I have written some correct HTML and passed this as a string into an email,

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd'>/n<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>X</th>
                <th>Y</th>
            </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Overall</td>
         <td>207,890</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>a</td>
         <td>100,568</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>b</td>
         <td>107,322</td>
      </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

I re-wrote the HTML to be extremely simple, only using a table but its still not showing??

Comment: As far as I remember from my experiments with HTML emails and Outlook, it doesn't like whole HTML documents. Try sending just the contents of the `<body>` with inline styling.

Comment: Can you verify that Outlook 2007 supports floating divs? The best answer is probably to use table elements to lay out content in a table.

Comment: @Douglas, oh dear you could be right: http://www.webpronews.com/kiss-your-css-goodbye-with-outlook-2007-01

Comment: @ShadowWizard Formally, you could say that for HTML email, the correct root element is body, not html.

Comment: One note though I don't think its the cause of your problems. That HTML isn't technically valid. You have a doctype saying it is XHTML but the `<meta>` tag is not closed.

Comment: I did this guys but it's still not working... see original message

Comment: is the /n suppose to be there on the first line?

Comment: @user1107474. Looks fine - I would strip down even further. Try without doc type - i've read that outlook 2007 ignores it. Try a title in the head. Also you've got \n between doc type and html - is that actually in the mark up? Or is it just cutting and pasting artifact?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally email clients don't seem to like decently formatted HTML. Just from conversation I've had with HTML developers

1. Use inline styles even if that means repeating yourself. No style sheets even in head
2. No fancy floating of the divs
3. Put everything in tables for formatting

Generally pretend like it's 1999

Comment: Pretent like it's 1999 - that summarizes the problem well I think :-D

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is probably not only Outlook 2007 but most other email clients as well.

Make sure that your html is very simple and does not use many external resources, inline CSS is probably necessary. This article is a nice summary: http://css-tricks.com/using-css-in-html-emails-the-real-story/

Comment: I have changed my html to just a table, but it still isnt showing?

Comment: If you are sending the email using the MailMessage class then you should set the IsBodyHtml property to true. Could that be the problem?